# Trying to enable RDP to Public IP, but it doesn't work. Router Arris

Tags: windows, router, remote-desktop, firewall, xrdp

Router Arris doesn't enable port 3389 to Public IP.

Router info:

Hardware Software Version
Serial Number
517192042224

Bootcode Version
2.2.0.45

Hardware Version
4

Firmware Version
9.1.103GE10

I follow the steps below to enable RDP to Public IP:

- I Enabled the port 3389 in the Firewall (Inbound and Outbound):
  [Inbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTL4G.png)
  [Outbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPdlg.png)
- I enabled the port 3389 on firewall in router config:
  [Firewall Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtgB4.png)
  [Port Forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za0Jg.png)
- And I checked if the port opened but that doesn't work:
  [Checking port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuWn0.png)

What I missed?

I appreciated who help me.

Comment: Are you behind a CGNAT? [Edit] your question to provide that required clarity. We don’t need the serial number to your router.

Comment: @Ramhound What's CGNAT? I just wanna access my PC from IP Public without using Teamviewer. you know?

Comment: If you search for CGNAT Bing and Google will do a better job explaining it than a comment limited to 500 characters.  The issues you describe suggest you are indeed behind a CGNAT.

Comment: (I can’t describe the concept of CGNAT in the limitation of a comment). Hence the reason i point to search for it, reading as much as you personally need to answer “what is CGNAT”, allowing you to provide the required clarification to your question in the form of an edit

Comment: See [How to check whether or not your ISP performs CGNAT](https://www.purevpn.com/blog/how-to-check-whether-or-not-your-isp-performs-cgnat/) and let us know the results.